# How to SELECT a date between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

How can I select from mysql with php a range between 2 dates?
The working day, start for example, at 7:00 am of 2022-01-01 and ends at 2:00 am of 2022-01-02. I want that all collected datas from 00:00 to 2:00 am of 2022-01-02 are grouped inside previous date.

Now I use this query

```
 SELECT date_format(dateAdded,"%m-%d") as mth,COUNT(productID) as total, productID FROM statisticsNW WHERE userID = "35" AND productID = "1193'" AND YEAR(dateAdded) = "2022" AND month(dateAdded) = "01" GROUP by year(dateAdded),month(dateAdded), day(dateAdded) ORDER by year(dateAdded),month(dateAdded)
```

and the result is this  but the "total" is wrong because is from 00:00 to 23:59 of the same day. The correct query the I want is from 7:00 to 6:59 of the next day. But from 00:00 to 6:59 datas must be counted in the previous day.

[image]

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and produce a [mre]

Comment: Subtract two hours from the given value, and then simply group by the resulting date portion? Or probably rather 2 hours and one minute, because with `2022-01-02 02:00` you still want to "land" in `2022-01-01`. And since your starting times are all >= 7am, you might as well subtract three full hours, because with 7am minus three hours, you still land on the same day.

Answer (score 0):

you can add 5 hours to the start_time and end_time, so the it appears the shift starts at midnight

```
select DATEDIFF(HH,cast('2022-01-24 19:00:00' as datetime),cast('2022-01-25 00:00:00' as datetime)) as time_5_hrs
```

[image: result]

```
select dateadd(HOUR,5,cast('2022-01-02 19:00:00' as datetime)) as starttime, dateadd(HOUR,5,cast('2022-01-03 02:00:00' as datetime)) as endtime,datediff(HH,dateadd(HOUR,5,cast('2022-01-02 19:00:00' as datetime)),dateadd(HOUR,5,cast('2022-01-03 02:00:00' as datetime))) diff
```

[image]

By doing this you can get both date are the same and you will be able to group it as single day.

Comment: True but OP states previous day in question..

Comment: My bad, you can reduce 2 hours from both start_date and end_date. need to replace the 5 with -2.

select dateadd(HOUR,-2,cast('2022-01-02 19:00:00' as datetime)) as starttime, dateadd(HOUR,-2,cast('2022-01-03 02:00:00' as datetime)) as endtime,datediff(HH,dateadd(HOUR,-2,cast('2022-01-02 19:00:00' as datetime)),dateadd(HOUR,-2,cast('2022-01-03 02:00:00' as datetime))) diff

Comment: if is more easy is correct also if range is from 2022-01-24 7:00:00 to  2022-01-25 6:59:00

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check.

Comment: you mean that shift starts at 7:00 PM and ends at 6:59 PM? so from 00:00 to end time should be considered as previous day?      if yes then you need to use a case statement, if the time is between 00:00 and 6:59, then you have to go back one day using dateadd function

Answer (score 0):

I have solved

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD("2017-06-15 5:30:00", INTERVAL 24 HOUR), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
```